# Which character set should be used for Mysql

Tags: mysql

My software will have multi lingual support.

Currently I am using UTF8.

Which character set is ideal for multi lingual text?

Comment: UTF-8 is good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, use `utf8mb4` as this will allow emoji.

Regular `utf8` will support only three byte characters, and while this is sufficient for most languages, if you have the opportunity, allowing for up to four is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `utf8_general_ci`, 8-bit UCS/Unicode. This should work for any.

Comment: Technically that's a *collation*, not a character set. Character sets affect how things are stored. Collation affects case insensitivity, equivalence and sorting.